# iOS Fido2 BLE authenticator register response issue

Tags: ios, webauthn, fido

I'm building an iOS ble fido2 authenticator. After receiving the register request sending the below register response (NONE attestation) as 3 chunks (chunksize 101). Also made sure chunks are received successfully But webauthn client is not sending any error / ack / no ui change is happening.

Struck with this problem for long time. Couldn't find out what goes wrong with the below response.

[131, 0, 237, 0, 163, 1, 100, 110, 111, 110, 101, 2, 88, 224, 116, 166, 234, 146, 19, 201, 156, 47, 116, 178, 36, 146, 179, 32, 207, 64, 38, 42, 148, 193, 169, 80, 160, 57, 127, 41, 37, 11, 96, 132, 30, 240, 69, 217, 93, 96, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 51, 85, 191, 68, 43, 240, 76, 144, 137, 91, 65, 40, 160, 206, 219, 169, 96, 183, 153, 21, 21, 63, 46, 204, 106, 131, 137, 30, 106, 102, 13, 92, 99, 165, 1, 2, 3, 38, 32, 1, 33, 152, 32, 24, 138, 24, 231, 24, 213, 24, 124, 24, 203, 24, 71, 24, 212, 24, 46, 16, 24, 184, 24, 207, 24, 210, 24, 170, 24, 59, 24, 99, 24, 39, 24, 250, 24, 81, 24, 98, 24, 27, 24, 25, 24, 39, 24, 75, 24, 202, 24, 62, 24, 163, 24, 64, 24, 126, 24, 214, 24, 63, 24, 247, 24, 197, 34, 152, 32, 12, 24, 214, 24, 121, 24, 78, 24, 132, 24, 152, 24, 104, 12, 18, 24, 120, 24, 156, 24, 177, 24, 101, 24, 45, 24, 227, 24, 177, 24, 213, 24, 151, 24, 76, 24, 136, 24, 121, 24, 39, 24, 47, 24, 153, 24, 196, 24, 24, 24, 100, 24, 82, 24, 163, 24, 83, 24, 193, 24, 38, 3, 160]

[131, 0, 237, 0, ......] 
131 => msg
0   => LLen
237 => HLen
0   => Success
 followed by authData....

AUTHDATA (224 bytes) 
[116, 166, 234, 146, 19, 201, 156, 47, 116, 178, 36, 146, 179, 32, 207, 64, 38, 42, 148, 193, 169, 80, 160, 57, 127, 41, 37, 11, 96, 132, 30, 240, 69, 217, 93, 96, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 51, 85, 191, 68, 43, 240, 76, 144, 137, 91, 65, 40, 160, 206, 219, 169, 96, 183, 153, 21, 21, 63, 46, 204, 106, 131, 137, 30, 106, 102, 13, 92, 99, 165, 1, 2, 3, 38, 32, 1, 33, 152, 32, 24, 138, 24, 231, 24, 213, 24, 124, 24, 203, 24, 71, 24, 212, 24, 46, 16, 24, 184, 24, 207, 24, 210, 24, 170, 24, 59, 24, 99, 24, 39, 24, 250, 24, 81, 24, 98, 24, 27, 24, 25, 24, 39, 24, 75, 24, 202, 24, 62, 24, 163, 24, 64, 24, 126, 24, 214, 24, 63, 24, 247, 24, 197, 34, 152, 32, 12, 24, 214, 24, 121, 24, 78, 24, 132, 24, 152, 24, 104, 12, 18, 24, 120, 24, 156, 24, 177, 24, 101, 24, 45, 24, 227, 24, 177, 24, 213, 24, 151, 24, 76, 24, 136, 24, 121, 24, 39, 24, 47, 24, 153, 24, 196, 24, 24, 24, 100, 24, 82, 24, 163, 24, 83, 24, 193, 24, 38]

```
1. RPID => [116, 166, 234, 146, ..., 240] position: {0 - 31} 32 BYTES
2. Flags => [69] position: {32} 1 BYTE
3. Counter => [217, 93, 96, 1] position: {33 - 36} 4 BYTES
4. Attestation Cred Data=> below
```

ATTESTATION CREDENTIAL DATA (187 bytes)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 51, 85, 191, 68, 43, 240, 76, 144, 137, 91, 65, 40, 160, 206, 219, 169, 96, 183, 153, 21, 21, 63, 46, 204, 106, 131, 137, 30, 106, 102, 13, 92, 99, 165, 1, 2, 3, 38, 32, 1, 33, 152, 32, 24, 138, 24, 231, 24, 213, 24, 124, 24, 203, 24, 71, 24, 212, 24, 46, 16, 24, 184, 24, 207, 24, 210, 24, 170, 24, 59, 24, 99, 24, 39, 24, 250, 24, 81, 24, 98, 24, 27, 24, 25, 24, 39, 24, 75, 24, 202, 24, 62, 24, 163, 24, 64, 24, 126, 24, 214, 24, 63, 24, 247, 24, 197, 34, 152, 32, 12, 24, 214, 24, 121, 24, 78, 24, 132, 24, 152, 24, 104, 12, 18, 24, 120, 24, 156, 24, 177, 24, 101, 24, 45, 24, 227, 24, 177, 24, 213, 24, 151, 24, 76, 24, 136, 24, 121, 24, 39, 24, 47, 24, 153, 24, 196, 24, 24, 24, 100, 24, 82, 24, 163, 24, 83, 24, 193, 24, 38]

```
1. AAGUID => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] position: {0 - 15} 16 BYTES
2. CredID len => [32] position: {17} 2 BYTES
3. CredID => [51, 85, 191, ... 92] position: {18....48} 32 BYTES
4. PubKey => [99, 165, ..., 38] position: {18....48} 138 BYTES
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you got **MTU** problem in bluetooth communication

let's say this is make credential response from authenticator to client

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

The size is 1014 bytes while MTU is just 101 bytes (for example).

What you have to do is splitting it to many packet with packet size is 101 bytes

> 8303F300A301667061636B65640258A4C46CEF82AD1B546477591D008B08759EC3E6D2ECB4F39474BFEA6969925D03B7450000000000112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF0020C04206F5430D6A902F2BFBDD063BD9FCE9FB68B10FC99DA93A01A51268D8
>
> 00E690A501020326200121582016B52F38710D6C002E47F8A7DF3AFA388C784F1A336B4182C004E16C137F9C992258209504397DCD350EFEC42AB01AE39ABE64B7B7C52531B470D0FE10C1FEDBFB2E7203A363616C67266373696758473045022100ADF472
>
> 01CC5BAB76EF5A8E23155525C74496C3E91EA81F0CFDDF2D353C2159BC78022052AC7BB3F403BE90C76BF7021FBE4FF909DB6319FE397C9897B4571172405CDE63783563815902E6308202E2308201CAA0030201020209009FA732A3246276C3300D06092A
>
> 02864886F70D01010B0500306B310B3009060355040613025347310B300906035504080C025347310F300D06035504070C064C6F6E646F6E310E300C060355040A0C05562D6B6579310B3009060355040B0C0250533121301F06035504030C184174746573
>
> 03746174696F6E20497373756572202D2042414F301E170D3139303631343034333132385A170D3239303631313034333132385A308183310B3009060355040613025347310B300906035504080C025347310F300D06035504070C064C6F6E646F6E310C30
>
> 040A060355040A0C0342414F31223020060355040B0C1941757468656E74696361746F72204174746573746174696F6E3124302206035504030C1B4174746573746174696F6E20636572746963617465202D2042414F3059301306072A8648CE3D02010608
>
> 052A8648CE3D0301070342000470E8468E66B1234C67E7BC5348CA5B9F47CA321B0D2D367376C6DAFFB6283B7C7AF8E05B05784A1ABE7273AD77C6655E2BC86AD491A89F284FC72007A07592EEA33B3039301F0603551D230418301680145D556C2CC12DCD
>
> 062D0EAB8A62A01F875F5E499BDA30090603551D1304023000300B0603551D0F0404030204F0300D06092A864886F70D01010B050003820101004FD8C7397DAA3BA23987282466F10CA754A2CE6ADD223F70C0977D672A36CD9A15B6476077C31B5E3E7BFF
>
> 07EB42D0EBCE819272A503B2710A1501B91E063B3DBAC79B3532AB063CA00EF7A644BE57BF2781710D93C50974CB209629135B1AE7904C56E6858FC3BD2F3DBBD90034D8A2B85E1A6EADCED52E62482B77739F1AB63391F1658E7BF3F7101C2665E2735E68
>
> 08635F0DBC70BE50E519503D4739FAB1D424AF966BCCD1A1098756A4B2E91CA37B38777FE1394E2BC007248B4317FA90E72760A4BCC45A7F9A9BC79B2012F67EF7FEC3899A52B816D5BFD42CA47E8EAF58FDD5F873D4CD1C9B32CD0AD7392E8046712E9007
>
> 09E1D7FEFBD3D0EF91A5B20A2E19

Do note that there is a sequence number in every packet, the first byte.

For every packet, you may use this method:

```
result = peripheralManager.updateValue(packet, for: <...>, onSubscribedCentrals: <...>)
```

Please do check the result, if it is FALSE, this method should be called

```
func peripheralManagerIsReady(toUpdateSubscribers peripheral: CBPeripheralManager)
```

Continue to send the rest packets

Comment: Hi Bao, thanks for the reply. My implementation is the same as what you have posted. I fixed the issue, Its problem with 'counter' byte length. Once again thanks for the reply and spend time to look into my issue :)